# How validate None and set a value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have df like This

```
   a  b  number 
0  s  d   100   
1  v  f  np.nan
2     e   10  
3  d  e
```

I want df like this

```
   a  b  number   status     Invalid
0  s  d   100      Valid       False  
1  v  f  np.nan    Not valid   True
2     e   10       Not valid   True
3  d  e            Not valid   True
```

for this condition is  if number value is >=1 then and A is contain Only `['S','V']` then  =Invalid True  and if a/number contain blank/NaN then this Invalid True and

i trying with this :

```
def check(df):
    if ((df['a'] in (['S','V'])) & ((df['number'])>=1)):
        return (True,'Not Valid')
    elif (df[['a','number']].isnull()).any()\
                or (df[['a','number']] == '').any():
        return (True,'Not Valid')
    else:
        return (False , "Valid")
df[['Invalid','Status']] = df.apply(check, axis = 1).tolist()
```

i try with above code but i getting error like

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

when ever Number is blank or Nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed some outputs from `return` for expected ouput:

```
#changed df to x for more clear x is row, not DataFrame
def check(x):
    #for scalar is used and instead &
    if ((x['a'] in (['s','v'])) and ((x['number'])>=1)):
        return (False,'Valid')
    elif (x[['a','number']].isnull()).any()\
                or (x[['a','number']] == '').any():
        return (True,'Not Valid')
    else:
        return (True , "Not Valid")
    
#converted column to numeric, if some non numeric values are generated NaNs
df['number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['number'], errors='coerce')
df[['Invalid','Status']] = df.apply(check, axis = 1).tolist()

print (df)
   a    b  number  Invalid     Status
0  s    d   100.0    False      Valid
1  v    f     NaN     True  Not Valid
2  e  NaN    10.0     True  Not Valid
3  d    e     NaN     True  Not Valid
```